# Problema com Jquery button

Tags: php, jquery, crud

Pessoal estou com um problema no meu código que talvez seja simples de resolver mas acabei ficando preso, estou fazendo um crud e os botões de adicionar, editar e deletar adicionei via Controller na construção das células da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meus botões ficaram repetidos por linha, ou seja, a cada linha da minha listagem de adições no banco de dados, constam os três botões;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando JQuery eu capturei o id do meu botão adicionar e redireciono para a página responsável pela inserção no banco de dados, mas somente meu botão adicionar da primeira linha funciona, os outros botões não possuem função nenhuma. Alguém poderia me explicar o que fiz de errado?
Segue meu código JQuery:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre pois todos os botões "Adicionar" possuem o mesmo ID. O mesmo acontece com os botões "Deletar" e "Editar". Nesse caso, apenas o primeiro botão é selecionado e, consequentemente, o evento só será atrelado a ele. Você poderia simplesmente utilizar classes ao invés de IDs para seleceionar os botões. O código ficaria assim:

PHP

```
echo "<td>
    <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-floating add">
        <i class="fa-plus fa"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-success btn-floating delete">
        <i class="fa-plus fa"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" name="edit" class="btn btn-success btn-floating edit">
        <i class="fa-plus fa"></i>
    </button>
</td>";
```

JavaScript

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'inserepessoa.php';
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mano, ajudou muito o feedback de vocês, as vezes esqueço da importância de utilizar class invés de id quando são vários do mesmo botão, solucionou meu problema!